# How can I use a conditional expression (expression with if and else) in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

I have a list comprehension that produces list of odd numbers of a given range:

```
[x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2]
```

That makes a filter that removes the even numbers. Instead, I'd like to use conditional logic, so that even numbers are treated differently, but still contribute to the list. I tried this code, but it fails:

```
>>> [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2 else x * 100]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2 else x * 100]
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that Python expressions allow a syntax like that:

```
1 if 0 is 0 else 3
```

How can I use it inside the list comprehension?

Comment: It took me a while to get why `if x % 2` **eliminates** even numbers (instead of keeping them) — it is because when `x` is even the `x % 2` expression results in `0`, which, in turn, evaluates to `False`, while any `int` except `0` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 476, accepted):

`x if y else z` is the syntax for the expression you're returning for each element. Thus you need:

```
[ x if x%2 else x*100 for x in range(1, 10) ]
```

The confusion arises from the fact you're using a *filter* in the first example, but not in the second. In the second example you're only *mapping* each value to another, using a ternary-operator expression.

With a filter, you need:

```
[ EXP for x in seq if COND ]
```

Without a filter you need:

```
[ EXP for x in seq ]
```

and in your second example, the expression is a "complex" one, which happens to involve an `if-else`.

Comment: I've got one question... `[x for x in range(1, 10) if x % 2]` is correct syntax. `[x if x % 2 for x in range(1, 10)]` - this is not, but `[x if x%2 else x*100 for x in range(1, 10)]` is again, correct syntax. How come?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz in your second example, this is neither a ternary-if-else operator (missing the `else`), nor a filter (since it is on the `EXP` part of the list comprehension)

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz To further clarify, note that you can add a second `if` at the end: `[x if x%2 else x*100 for x in range(1, 10) if not x%3]` The first `if` is part of the ternary operator, the second `if` is part of the list comprehension syntax. The whole `x if x%2 else x*100` is "on the same level" as a simple `2*x`, it's the expression to evaluate on the left side of the `for`, when the filtering of `if not x%3` has already taken place.

Comment: Hello, would a one-line statement be more performant than making it on two lines like `for i in x:` and then in the for loop `if i == y:` ?

Answer (score 31):

```
[x if x % 2 else x * 100 for x in range(1, 10) ]
```

Answer (score 20):

You can do that with list comprehension too:

```
A=[[x*100, x][x % 2 != 0] for x in range(1,11)]
print A
```

Comment: Very nice.  A boolean slice. Thanks you just gave me an easier to read solution.

Comment: You can also double assign like so: A,B = [10,11][a==19],[1,14][a==20]

Answer (score 15):

Just another solution, hope some one may like it :

Using: [False, True][Expression]

```
>>> map(lambda x: [x*100, x][x % 2 != 0], range(1,10))
[1, 200, 3, 400, 5, 600, 7, 800, 9]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

#how you can squre a list of an array of negative and positive values

```
my_list=[-2,-3,0,1,5]
squred_values=[]
  

squred_values=[-i**2 if i<0 else i**2 for i in my_list]
```

#or

```
for i in my_list:
    if i<0:
        squred_values.append( -i**2)`enter code here`
    else:
        squred_values.append( i**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

two for in one list comprehension

```
ex = [['obi', 'is', '#alive'],['oge', 'is', 'beautiful'],
                ['Ade', 'the', '#comedian', 'de', '#rich'],['Jesus', 'wept']]
res = [j if j.startswith("#") else "_"+j for i in ex for j in i]
```

Comment: I don't see what information this answer adds over the much older and explained existing answers...