# python replace None with blank in list using list Comprehensions or something else? Also a nested list solution

Tags: python, list-comprehension

`a = [None, None, '2014-04-27 17:31:17', None, None]`

trying to replace `None` with `''`

tried many times, this the closest I got. `b= ['' for x in a if x==None]` which gives me four `''` but leaves out the date

i thought it would be `b= ['' for x in a if x==None else x]` but doesn't work.

what if it is nested like so:

`a = [[None, None, '2014-04-27 17:31:17', None, None],[None, None, '2014-04-27 17:31:17', None, None],[None, None, '2014-04-27 17:31:17', None, None]]`

Can you still use list comprehensions?

Comment: When you compare something with `None` use `is` operator ([description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or))

Comment: `None` and `''` are two very different things; be sure it doesn't have an impact somewhere else.

Comment: yeah, reading from google sheets blank become `None`, but to put them back to the same position you have change `None` back to `''`, or else it will be a page of `None`s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just modify your code as follows:

```
b = ['' if x is None else x for x in a]    #and use is None instead of == None

>>> print b
['', '', '2014-04-27 17:31:17', '', '']
```

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321138/python-one-line-list-comprehension-if-else-variants/17321170#17321170)

For nested lists, you can do:

```
b = [['' if x is None else x for x in c] for c in a]
```

Comment: what about for a nested list?

Comment: @jason_cant_code, Answer updated. Hope that helps

Comment: @Downvoter, Why the downvote? Anything wrong with my answer? Please let me know so I can improve it. Thank you

Comment: @sshashank124: complete accident. I have no idea how it happened o.O changed it to an upvote!

Answer (score 5):

You don't even have to use a comprehension:

`a = map(lambda x: '' if x == None else x, a)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `or` operator for this:

```
>>> a = [None, None, '2014-04-27 17:31:17', None, None]
>>> print [x or "" for x in a]
['', '', '2014-04-27 17:31:17', '', '']
```

..because the `or` operator works like so:

```
>>> None or ""
''
>>> "blah" or ""
'blah'
```

..although this might not be ideal, as it will replace any [False'ish values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), e.g:

```
>>> 0 or ""
''
```

If this is a problem in your case, the more explicit `['' if x is None else x for x in a]` mentioned in sshashank124's answer which will only replace `None` specifically

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comprehension if you know in advance how deep the list is nested (although it wouldn't be particularly readable), for arbitrary nested lists you can use a simple "recursive map" function like this:

```
def maprec(obj, fun):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [maprec(x, fun) for x in obj]
    return fun(obj)
```

Usage:

```
new_list = maprec(nested_list, lambda x: '' if x is None else x)
```