# list comprehensions with if/else in biopython

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension, biopython

I would like this carried out in a single list comprehension:

```
for rec in SeqIO.parse(infile2, "fastq"):
    if rec.id+"_RC" in RCList:
        rec.reverse_complement(id=rec.id,description="")
    else:
        rec
```

This works:

```
good_reads = ( rec.reverse_complement(id=rec.id,description="") for rec in SeqIO.parse(infile2, "fastq") if rec.id+"_RC" in RCList )
```

If I put in else into this line there are general invalid syntax errors:

> (1) reads = ( rec.reverse_complement(id=rec.id,description="") for rec in SeqIO.parse(infile2, "fastq") if rec.id+"_RC" in RCList rec if not rec.id+"_RC" in RCList)

or the same goes with:

> (2) reads = ( rec.reverse_complement(id=rec.id,description="") for rec in SeqIO.parse(infile2, "fastq") if rec.id+"_RC" in RCList else (rec))

Finally, I am using SeqIO to write this to a file

> SeqIO.write(good_reads,infile2+".RC.fastq", "fastq")

What is wrong with the above in (1) and (2) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python one-line list comprehension: if-else variants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321138/python-one-line-list-comprehension-if-else-variants)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions, and generator expressions, can be a little bit confusing because they use the keyword `if` but it's not the same as the usual `if` in Python.

Listcomps and genexps have this format:

```
expression for x in iterable if condition
```

The `if condition` part will be evaluated, and if the result is true, the `expression` part will be evaluated and (for a listcomp) the value will appear in the new list; or (for a genexp) the value will appear among the values yielded up.  But there is no provision for an `else` here.

You can do exactly what you want using the ternary `if` in Python.  You can have an expression with this format:

```
true_expression if condition else false_value
```

`condition` will be evaluated.  If the result is true, then `true_expression` will be evaluated and the result returned; if the result of `condition` is false, then `false_value` will be evaluated and the result returned.  This is all one expression.

Some people think it improves readability to put the ternary `if` into parentheses:

```
(true_expression if condition else false_value)
```

You can use the ternary expression described above as the `expression` part of your listcomp or genexp.

So, you can use it like so:

```
good_reads = ( rec.reverse_complement(id=rec.id,description="") if rec.id+"_RC" in RCList else rec for rec in SeqIO.parse(infile2, "fastq")  )
```

See also:

[Is it possible to use 'else' in a python list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-python-list-comprehension)

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that!  Thanks so much for the explanation, very concise.

Comment: And what if an 'elif' equivalent was used instead of the final else?  If I attach an 'if' statement after the 'else' it only yields the else results and not the first if condition.

Comment: There is no `elif` inside an expression.  But!  You can do what you want!  Note that there are actually three expressions inside the ternary: `true_expression`, `condition`, and `false_expression`.  Any one of these can, itself, be a ternary expression.  But it will quickly get crazy-looking.  You might just make a helper function and put any sort of `if` statements you like inside it, and then just call the helper function:  `good_reads = ( helper_function(rec) for rec in SeqIO.parse(infile2, "fastq")  )`

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thanks so much for your help, the program is nice and fast now.