# Emulating a pass in a ternary operator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a list comprehension where I grab a list of keys from a dictionary, ignoring certain specified ones.

```
[x if x not in ignoreKeys else None for x in entity]
```

I'm currently using else None as my way of not appending the ignored keys, but ideally I would get the list comprehension to pass over that iteration. Unfortunately pass gives a syntax error, so I'm wondering if there might be some way I can emulate the pass functionality?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17321138/2096752

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `else` at all, just use `if` :

```
[x for x in entity if x not in ignoreKeys]
```

This will return the values that are not in `ignoreKeys`.

Comment: Aha! I had only tried this with if on the other side. Works perfectly!