# Python list comprehension with conditional and double for loop syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, list-comprehension

I am trying to count the number of times the elements in my list 'predicted' equal the corresponding elements in my list 'actual' when said 'actual' elements equal 1 (the number of 'true positives').

Here's my code:

```
def F_approx(predicted, actual):
   est_tp = np.sum([int(p == a) if a for p in predicted for a in actual])
   est_fn = np.sum([int(p !=a) if a for p in predicted for a in actual])
   est_recall = est_tp / (est_tp + est_fn)
   pr_pred_1 = np.sum([int(p == 1) for p in predicted]) / len(predicted)
   est_f = np.power(est_recall, 2) / pr_pred_1
   return(est_f)
```

Which looks correct to *my* eye, but I get an error:

```
    File "<ipython-input-17-3e11431566d6>", line 2
       est_tp = np.sum([int(p == a) if a for p in predicted for a in actual])
                                           ^ 
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` goes *after* the looping expression:

```
[int(p == a) for p in predicted for a in actual if a]
```

---

However, it really looks like you want to `zip` these together:

```
[int(p == a) for p, a in zip(predicted, actual)]
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I just read an answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321138/python-one-line-list-comprehension-if-else-variants that seems to suggest the opposite (at least for an if else case). Why does it work there and not here?

Comment: Never mind, I can answer my own question. This example is a filter, the other is not.

Comment: List comprehensions have the following syntax (approximately):  `[expression for var in loop_expression if filter_expression]`.  Those expressions can be just about anything -- including "conditional expressions" which have the form:  `expression if conditional else conditional`.  Note that the `else` is required to make the conditional expression.

Comment: @HudsonCooper -- Also note that if `predicted` and `actual` are `np.ndarray`, you can probably do:  `np.sum(predicted == array)` as a shortcut :-)

Answer (score 1):

the if is placed at the end of the list comprehension

```
[int(p == a) for p in predicted for a in actual if a]
```

as a side note, with your particular construct you can add a ternary operation and have an else in your list comprehension

```
[int(p == a) if a else '' for p in predicted for a in actual if a]
```

adding else to the end of the list comprehension will throw a `SyntaxError`