# Indent-Expected errors while trying to write one-line list comprehension: if-else variants

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a list with if-else statements in one line. I've followed the instructions in this
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321138/one-line-list-comprehension-if-else-variants), but I got multiple **"indent-Expected"** errors.

Here is my code:

```
initial= [[1,2,3],[],[]]
for block in initial:
    '''
    If block is empty move to the next block
    '''
    if not block: # empty?
        continue # change the block
    elif block: # full?
        packet = block[0]
        # True if there is an empty sublist
        x = [True for i in initial if len(i) == 0]
        # Enter if there is no empty sublist
        if not any(x):
            # Here is the issue
            if packet > max([continue if sublist == block  else sublist[-1] for sublist in initial]):
                continue
        block.remove(packet)
        break # New-one
```

The issue in this line:

```
if packet > max([continue if sublist == block  else sublist[-1] for sublist in initial]):
```

Comment: `continue` is a reserved keyword in python, what are you trying to?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia In the comprehensive list, while I am traversing the initial list's elements  I need to ignore some elements because of that I added `continue if sublist == block`.

Comment: use `0` or a negative value since you are anyway using the `max()` of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` is a reserved keyword in Python so you are getting the error.

You don't need a `continue` to skip element.

Further an `if` without `else` is complete in list `comprehension`.

Based on comments, if you just need to skip elements you can just use an `if` without an `else`.

Here is a dummy example to show what you need:

```
initial = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
block = [1, 2]
res = max([sublist[-1] for sublist in initial if sublist != block]) # just if is enough without else
print(res)
```